# ALSA - samplerate conversion

Tags: c++, audio, usb, alsa, resampling

I have a text-to-speech application, that generate an audio-stream (raw-data) with a samplerate of 22kHz.

I have a USB-SoundCard that support only 44kHz.

With my asound.conf I can play wav-files that contains 22kHz and 44kHz audio-stream without problems in aplay.

My Application use the alsa-libs and set the samplerate of the device.
In this case only 44kHz will succeed, because the hardware supports only this samplerate. But now, when i write the generated audio-stream to alsa, it sounds wrong, because the samplerates dosn't match. The audio-stream (raw-data) dosn't contain any header information, so I think alsa don't use any plugin zu convert the samplerate. Alsa don't know that the stream has a different samplerate

My question is now, what is the right way to tell alsa, that the generated audio-stream have a different samplerate, so the alsa-plugin convert it.

The following code works on the USB SoundCard only with *sampleRate = 44100*, otherwise an error occured (-22, invalid parameters).

```
void initAlsa()
{
    const char* name = "default";

    alsaAudio = true;
    writeRiffAtClose = false;
    int err = snd_pcm_open (&alsaPlaybackHandle, name, SND_PCM_STREAM_PLAYBACK, 0);
    if (err < 0)
        throw TtsException({"Alsa: cannot open playback audio device ", name, " (" , snd_strerror (err), ")"}, 0);

    sampleRate = 44100;
    err = snd_pcm_set_params(alsaPlaybackHandle,                 // pcm PCM handle
                             SND_PCM_FORMAT_S16_LE,                 // format required PCM format
                             SND_PCM_ACCESS_RW_INTERLEAVED,      // access required PCM access
                             2,                                  // channels required PCM channels (Stereo)
                             sampleRate,                         // rate required sample rate in Hz
                             1,                                  // soft_resample 0 = disallow alsa-lib resample stream, 1 = allow resampling
                             250000);          /* 0.25sec */     // latency required overall latency in us
    if (err < 0)
        throw TtsException({"Alsa: cannot set parameters (" , err, " = " , snd_strerror(err), ") on ", name}, 0);

    LOG_DEBUG("Alsa audio initialized");
}
```

Other way are, I manuelly convert the sample rate, before i put it to alsa, but i think: why not use the alsa-plugin.

I don't have the option to get 44kHz audio-stream from the tts-engine (it's another software).

Or exist another way, that I don't see?

Best regards.

Comment: What did you do to your `asound.conf`?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/jjZuqt9c

Comment: In theory, the `plug` plugin does automatic resampling. I see no reason why that code wouldn't work.

Comment: Can you try to add `defaults.pcm.rate_converter "linear"` line to the beginning of asound.conf? Maybe for some reason the default ALSA sample rate conversion is not engaged, let's try to force it